# Storing numpy arrays as PyTables cell element

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pytables

I have 4 files with data in the following format: 3 files contain numpy arrays with different dimensions, say, 20, 30 and 25. The number of records in each file is the same, say 10000. The fourth file contains 1000 floats (as many as arrays in each file).
I attempt to create a table based on these files with the following structure:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| VecsFile #0   | VecsFile #1   | VecsFile #2   | FloatFile |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|np.ndarray(20,)|np.ndarray(30,)|np.ndarray(25,)|   0.1     |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|np.ndarray(20,)|np.ndarray(30,)|np.ndarray(25,)|   0.2     |
                               ...
```

By I encountered that PyTables doesn't receive numpy array as valid type for cell data.

Code:
    import tables
    import numpy as np

```
def create_table_def(n_files):
    table_def = dict()
    for rnum in range(n_files):
        table_def['VecsFile #'+str(rnum)] = tables.Col.from_atom(tables.Float64Atom())
    table_def['FloatFile'] = tables.Col.from_atom(tables.Float64Atom())

    return table_def

r0 = np.load('file0.npy')
r1 = np.load('file1.npy')
r2 = np.load('file2.npy')
s = np.random.rand(*r0.shape)


with tables.open_file('save.hdf', 'w') as saveFile:
    table_def = create_table_def(3)
    table = saveFile.create_table(saveFile.root, 'que_vectors', table_def)
    tablerow = table.row
    for i in range(r0.shape[0]):
        print(r0[i])
        tablerow['VecsFile #0'] = r0[i]
        tablerow['VecsFile #1'] = r1[i]
        tablerow['VecsFile #2'] = r2[i]
        tablerow['FloatFile'] = s[i]
        tablerow.append()
    table.flush()
```

And I get the following traceback:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/scratch_6.py", line 27, in <module>
    tablerow['VecsFile #0] = r0[i]
  File "tables\tableextension.pyx", line 1591, in tables.tableextension.Row.__setitem__
TypeError: invalid type (<class 'numpy.ndarray'>) for column ``VecsFile #0``
```

Am I doing something wrong? Or is this way to store such vectors and column with floats as one file without appending all these vectors to a numpy matrix? I want to use it for appending rows with vectors and one float in future, ranging them and delete them.

Comment: I'm more familiar with the `h5py` interface to `HDF5`, which has an almost one-to-one mapping of numpy arrays.  `pytables` is more complex, but I'm surprised that it has problems saving arrays as cell elements.  The cells of the DataFrame are object dtype.  `h5py` can't save object dtype arrays.

Comment: Could you save `r0`, `r1`, etc as their own `datasets` in the `h5` file?  I know how to do that with `h5py`.

Comment: I'd suggest saving a simple dataframe, and the look at file with `h5dump`(or other general purpose viewer) to get an idea of the structure pytables uses.  `h5py` makes HDF5 groups to dictionary like, and datasets like numpy arrays.

Comment: In other SO questions people have had trouble saving this kind of dataframe to csv files.  Pandas turns the array elements into strings, and saves those as column values.  Pandas load can't (readily) convert the strings back into arrays.

Comment: I mistakenly assumed you were using `pandas`, though `pandas` does use `pytables` for writing HDF5.  In any case, I don't see `object` dtype listed here:  https://www.pytables.org/usersguide/datatypes.html.

Comment: @hpaulj Tkhank you for suggestion, I will try to store `r0`, `r1` and `r2` as separate datasets in h5 file, but will I be able to rerange, filter and clean them alltogether?

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
import tables as tb


class NumpyTable(tb.IsDescription):
    """ define a table with cells of 84 x 84"""
    numpy_cell = tb.Float32Col(shape=(84, 84))


""" open a file and create the table """
fileh = tb.open_file('numpy_cell.h5', mode='w')
group = fileh.create_group(fileh.root, 'group')
filters = tb.Filters(complevel=5, complib='zlib')
np_table = fileh.create_table('/group', 'numpy_table', NumpyTable, "group: NumpyTable",
                              filters=filters)

""" get the last row """
row = np_table.row

""" add a row """
row['numpy_cell'] = np.zeros((84, 84), dtype=np.float32)
row.append()

""" add another row """
row['numpy_cell'] = np.ones((84, 84), dtype=np.float32)
row.append()

""" write to disk and close the file"""
np_table.flush()
fileh.close()

""" check it """
fileh = tb.open_file('numpy_cell.h5', mode='r')
assert np.allclose(
  fileh.root.group.numpy_table[0]['numpy_cell'], 
  np.zeros((84, 84), dtype=np.float32)
)
assert np.allclose(
  fileh.root.group.numpy_table[1]['numpy_cell'], 
  np.ones((84, 84), dtype=np.float32)
)
fileh.close()
```